# VmmemWSL killing my RAM; unable to delete through common means

Tags: docker, ubuntu, virtual-machine

So I just started getting into VMs and I went through the standard procedure installing Linux and Ubuntu on my laptop , since then I can’t run Any Windows tabs or application due to its high RAM storage.
I attempted wsl —- shutdown in power shell administrator along with all the standard lines found online but it says that , This file cannot be accessed my the system ‘ . I’m lost and I can’t open notepad to add the fix file because the service cannot accept control messages at this time.
Hyper v manager is non existent , even though I have permission enabled . All in all , nothing works . Please help !!!!

Wsl —-shutdown ; file can’t be accessed
Wsl -l -v ; file can’t be accessed
Notepad config file ; can’t open notepad
Docker is unresponsive… I am in the deep here